# If a language has no "bit to bit" comparison, how do I simulate it?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script in the (beta) Trackmania 2 game.
(It's an ugly kindof mix between JavaScript, HTML, C, and... other stuff I couldn't imagine in my worst nightmare).

The scripting engine doesn't seem to know the "and" or "&&" (if I try `myVar && 16` the nice error raised is "boolean operation awaits a boolean")

I'd like to do something like:

```
if (Var && 1) {
  // Bit North => trace north
}

if (Var && 2) {
  // Bit East => trace east
}
if (Var && 4) {
  // Bit South => trace south
}
if (Var && 8) {
  // Bit West => trace West
}
```

Any idea how I could do this if the compiler doesn't know bitfield operations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Bitwise and" is usually `&`, not `&&`. (`&&` is usually a "logical and".) "Bitwise and" is `&` in C and JavaScript, two languages you mentioned. In fact, `&&` appears to be "logical and" bassd on the error message you got. The solution might simply be to use

```
if (Var & 1)
```

If you really don't have bitwise ops, it can still be done. Keep in mind that a 4 bit number can be expressed as:

```
b3 * 2**3 + b2 * 2**2 + b1 * 2**1 + b0 * 2**0
```

If you have exponentiation, division, integer truncation and modulus, you could use the following to see if to find out if bit `x` is set:

```
int( i / (2**x) ) % 2
```

If you don't have exponentiation, it can be replaced with a lookup table.

If you don't have modulus, `i % 2` can be replaced with `( (i/2) - int(i/2) )*2`

Comment: Thank you very much that did the trick. So nice to find smart & clever people all around the world!